# Specifying the line width of the legend frame, in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib, how do I specify the line width and color of a legend frame?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For the width: `legend.get_frame().set_linewidth(w)`

For the color: `legend.get_frame().set_edgecolor("red")`

Comment: this could be made much clearer by providing an example

Answer (score 8):

Got the answer:

```
legend = axes.legend()
frame = legend.get_frame()
```

and then we can use `frame.set_XXX` to specify the properties of the frame.

Didn't find it at first because it's not an input argument of the `plt.legend()` method.

Comment: How can you do this while doing `ax.legend`? I've set up a `legend_kws` kwargs for my wrappers