# Matplotlib: is there an rcParams way to adjust legend border width?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend-properties

[This site](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) shows many (all?) rc parameters that can be adjusted in Matplotlib plots, either through the `matplotlibrc` file or using `matplotlib.rcParams[]` in a Python script.  I can see no way to adjust the width of the border box of a legend using the parameters listed in that site.  I know it is possible to change the line width of the box "manually", i.e., in the script ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058485/specifying-the-line-width-of-the-legend-frame-in-matplotlib)), but I'm hoping for a way to set it using `matplotlib.rcParams[]` or in a `matplotlibrc` file.  How could I do this?

The reason I care to have an automated, external (or at least easily copy-and-pastable) is because I have several figures, with several different Python scripts producing these several figures, and I would like as easy a way as possible to maintain a standard look between each of these figures, across the different Python scripts.

In some scripts I call for a legend as `pyplot.legend()` and in others I call for it as `ax.legend()`.

Comment: You may not be able to do this via rcParams, but I bet there is a property you can set somewhere in the legend class to do this.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, an automated way to set it?

Comment: I am assuming that you can automate something like `matplotlib.legend.Legend.myMagicProperty = 25` as well as you can `matplotlib.rcParams['my.magic.param'] = 25`.

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/legend.py) around line 359 to see how the patch used to draw the legend gets initialized.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why setting the line width for a new legend in a script using `set_linewidth` is not "automated" enough for you?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I have several figures I'm making for a paper, with several different Python scripts producing these several figures.  I was hoping for a way to set this property external of any of these scripts so that I could get a consistent look between all my figures with a minimum of effort. Or at least have a `matplotlib.rcParams[]` statement I could quickly copy and paste between all my scripts and put right at the top, instead of having to search through the script to find where `matplotlib.legend()` is called.

Comment: That makes much more sense than what I was expecting. Could you put that into your question? I just thought of a different way to do it from the answer I am drafting based on what you just said.

Comment: Also, how are you calling `legend`? `plt.legend` or `ax.legend`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, updated my question to answer your question.  Answer: both.

Comment: Updated my answer to note that it explicitly works with both. One is just a wrapper for the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to do, it may in fact be possible to set the width of the legend border via `rcParams`.

**TL;DR**

Set `patch.linewidth` in `matplotlibrc` or better yet, write a two-line wrapper function for `legend` and use that instead in your scripts.

**Long Version**

Looking at the code for `legend`, you can see that the frame stored as a `matplotlib.patched.FancyBBoxPatch` object, which is a type of `matplotlib.patches.Patch`. `Patch` objects get their default line width from `matplotlib.rcParams['patch.linewidth']`. This means that if you set `patch.linewidth` in `matplotlibrc`, the size of the legend border will change.

A similar modification to `patch.edgecolor` will change the border color, but `patch.facecolor` will be ignored for legends.

Here is a code sample to illustrate the change, with some outputs:

```
>>> import matplotlib as mpl
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> mpl.rcParams['patch.linewidth']
1.0
>>> plt.plot((0, 1), label='a')[0].axes.legend()
<matplotlib.legend.Legend object at 0x7f6d7b0a0e48>
>>> mpl.rcParams['patch.linewidth'] = 15
>>> plt.plot((0, 1), label='a')[0].axes.legend()
<matplotlib.legend.Legend object at 0x7f6d7ae20908>
```

[image: normal line legend]

[image: 15px line legend]

The obvious issue here is that if you draw any other patches on your charts, the default line width will be thrown off. You can of course mitigate this by "manually" changing the line width back to 1 for all the patches you create. Clearly this is not an optimal solution.

**A Better Way**

A much better solution would be to create a small script that you would share between all your chart generation scripts. Here is a sample of such a script:

```
from matplotlib.axes import Axes

def add_legend(ax, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Adds a legend to the specified axes, along with some common formatting. All additional arguments are the same as for `ax.legend`.
    """
    legend = _originalFn(ax, *args, **kwargs)
    legend.set_linewidth(15)
    return legend

if Axes.legend is not add_legend:
    _originalFn = Axes.legend
    Axes.legend = add_legend
```

This script is structured in such a way that you do not ever need to call `add_legend` manually. Just importing the script subclasses `matplotlib.axes.Axes` so that calling `ax.legend(...)` as before will set the default legend border width to 15 points.

The script above will work for calls to `ax.legend` where `ax` is an `Axes` instance and on `plt.legend`, since `plt.legend` really just delegates to `gca().legend` with some additional processing.

This subclassing mechanism will work even if your program consists of multiple scripts/modules which import the shared script. This is because Python will not actually reload the module after the first time, and will instead just return a reference to it, with all attributes intact. Things will break if you start using `importlib.reload`, but that is only a very remote possibility.

Comment: with current versions of matplotlib it has to be `legend.get_frame().set_linewidth(...)`